# Check if a user already made a submission with Doctrine- Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 3 entities which are `User`, `Problem` and `Submission`. I'm trying to restrict a user from solving the same question more than once if that user already solved it. I created  a method in `User` entity by checking the `Submissions` for each user. However I couldn't figure out a way to match the problem_id and user_id fields so I can see if the submission was correct or not.

Here are the entites;
Problem.php

```
class Problem
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=True)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter a valid title")
 */
protected $title;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter a valid description")
 */
protected $description;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter a valid value")
 */
protected $points;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter a valid flag")
 */
protected $flag;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter a valid value")
 */
protected $category;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="problems")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="createdby", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $createdby;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Submission", mappedBy="problem_id")
 */
protected $submissions;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title"})
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=false,)
 */
protected $slug;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $createdAt;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $updatedAt;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Discussion", mappedBy="problem")
 */
private $discussions;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
protected $isPublished = True;
}
```

Submission.php

```
class Submission
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Problem", inversedBy="submissions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="problem_id", referencedColumnName="id",  onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $problem_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $correct = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="submissions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Flag cannot be blank")
     */
    protected $submission_flag;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;
}
```

User.php
    class User implements UserInterface
    {

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter a valid email address")
 * @Assert\Email()
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter a valid email address")
 */
private $usrname;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
 */
private $plainPassword;

/**
 * The below length depends on the "algorithm" you use for encoding
 * the password, but this works well with bcrypt.
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter a valid name")
 */
private $fullname;

/**
 * @var array
 * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="json_array")
 */
protected $roles;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Problem", mappedBy="createdby")
 */
protected $problems;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Feed", mappedBy="createdby")
 */
protected $feeds;


/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="createdby")
 */
protected $comments;


/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Submission", mappedBy="user_id")
 */
protected $submissions;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to try @UniqueConstraint on your Submission entity.  Something like:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="unique_user_submission", columns={"name", "email"})})
 */
class Submission
{
}
```

I think that'll make those two fields a composite unique field.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-uniqueconstraint

Comment: That way a user will only be able to make a submission once even if it was wrong. In my case I want users to make a submission once only if the submission was right. If the submission was wrong user can make multiple submissions until they get it right.

Comment: In that case you'd want to do that check in your controller.  You'd check the entity for whatever logic, then perform updates on it and persist/flush it.  I try to keep as much logic out of my entities as possible.